# scipy interpolate barycentric lagrange

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have been reading about different ways to interpolate, for example- [this article](https://mmas.github.io/interpolation-scipy). It recommends using *barycentric_lagrange* instead of lagrange because it is more stable, runs in O(n) instead of O(n^2). This is all well and good, but I'd like to know how it is different than lagrange by itself.
What I am looking for is a **qualitative** explanation of the difference between barycentric and traditional lagrange.
I've tried looking at [mathematical papers](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/barycentric.pdf) about it, but the math is not easy to follow.

Are the "weights" just a way of weighting points close to the points that you are interpolating? That would be great if it was that simple.

Answer (score 1):

I found through some experimentation that barycenctric lagrange does not "weight" points like I had hoped. It is still very unstable if your input arrays are large (i.e. it still tries to construct the nth degree polynomial).
Barycentric has stability improvements for when the *values* are large.
Lagrange is good if your x and y are close to 0. So x = [20000, 20001, 20002] will be much less stable than [0, 1, 2]. The weights in barycentric, therefore, are simply a way of scaling your values to 0.
So the lagrange interpolation as follows:

```
x_scaled = x - x[0]
y_scaled = y - y[0]
polynomial = scipy.lagrange(x_scaled, y_scaled)
interp_y = polynomial(interp_x - x[0]) + y[0]
```

is the same as:

```
interp_y = scipy.barycentric_interpolate(x, y, interp_x)
```

So obviously the second one is much easier to implement in code, and they give the same result.